# what constitues user gesture

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-fullscreen

I recently programmed a menu interface for javascript that lets you dynamically add options to it and mostly works with mouseEnter Events . I thne added some basic video Controls to it with request/exit Fullscreen that trigger on one of these mouseEnter events most of the time it displays `Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.` however (weird part :) sometimes it works and im not sure how the browser api decides wether an action is a user gesture or not oO any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: a current suspicion I have is that its more likely to work directly at site startup (maybe its a timing thing and the code executes faster without having loaded too much else )

Answer (score 14):

Here is the list of events that can trigger "*by user activation*" as [defined by the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#user-activation-processing-model):

- change
- click
- contextmenu
- dblclick
- mouseup
- pointerup
- reset
- submit
- touchend

This is what your error message refers to when they say "a user gesture".

`mouseenter` is not part of this list.

Most likely, when it worked, it was because one of those event did happen less than a few ms before (IIRC it's 50ms in Chrome currently).

Answer (score 0):

For what this is worth, I've been consistently successful triggering actions that require user gestures when using `addEventListener()` calls to monitor for user events on elements. I've not been successful using the old `onClick` attributes to specify an event for an element.