# How to persist cross-domain data in the browser sent using `window.postMessage` - what counts as a "user gesture" for the Storage Access API?

Tags: javascript, postmessage, third-party-cookies, storage-access-api

I have 2 sites with different domains, a.com and b.com. I am sending a piece data from a.com to b.com using [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) with b.com loaded into an iframe on a.com. After that, I attempt to make the received data into a cookie on b.com - but it appears to be limited by [state partitioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Privacy/State_Partitioning#state_partitioning). I have [Firefox],

`Partitioned cookie or storage access was provided to “b.com” because it is loaded in the third-party context and dynamic state partitioning is enabled.`

So I am trying to use the [Storage Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_Access_API/Using#checking_and_requesting_storage_access) to allow the cookie to be saved. I see that

> `requestStorageAccess()` requests [...] need to be run inside some kind of user gesture-based event handler

The problem with this is that the b.com iframe on a.com is not shown (`display: none`). Is there a way I can prompt a response from users with something like [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) and have that work as a "[user gesture-based event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56388462/9890027)" instead of them interacting directly with the invisible b.com iframe?

---

I have seen multiple answers on Stack Exchange which suggest that `window.postMessage` is completely valid. First, there was a huge [iframe pitfall](https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication#iframe-wrong-document-pitfall) (classic iframes). Now there is state partitioning, which besides being an annoyance in itself, *requires user interaction* (a dealbreaker). More and more this is seeming like a terrible hack and not the robust solution it was made out to be.

This is for science at this point (since the other method of cross-domain communication - a redirect with params - should also work for my use case).